# Contrast enhancement using a percentage cumulative count in Matplolib

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I am writing a small program to align images based on manually selected points and I display both images next to each other. To have similar colors for similar raster values I'd like to stretch the colorbar to the same values for both images. In QGIS there is a possibility to use a cumulative count cut where you can input percentages to enhance the contrast of a raster. [image: QGIS screenshot]
I would like to find the corresponding (2% and 98%) raster values in my singleband raster image using matplotlib. Then I'd use the smallest 2% value and the largest 98% value as the vmin and vmax for my images.

I can't seem to find the function in matplotlib so does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is [percentile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) function.

Instead of using `matplotlib`, you may use some math for getting the desired result.

You can find lower and upper percentile using `percentile` function, and "stretch" pixel range linearly between lower and upper percentiles.

Here is a code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('chelsea.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read input image for testing

min_percent = 2   # Low percentile
max_percent = 98  # High percentile
lo, hi = np.percentile(img, (min_percent, max_percent))

# Apply linear "stretch" - lo goes to 0, and hi goes to 1
res_img = (img.astype(float) - lo) / (hi-lo)

#Multiply by 255, clamp range to [0, 255] and convert to uint8
res_img = np.maximum(np.minimum(res_img*255, 255), 0).astype(np.uint8)

#Display images before and after linear "stretch":
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('res_img', res_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:

Input image:
[image]

Output image:
[image]