# improve image quality in video with opencv videowriter python

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I am trying to create video from the images which are read from the binary log file. However, the output video is low but the output file properties looks good with file size and same settings for the image size, fps and duration. Here is my code.

Currently the img size before resize is

I hope I am not doing anything wrong with the image size settings.

I created the file using the below command:

`data.astype('int16').tofile(r"data1.out")`

Once I have the `data` I perform the following steps to get `img` since the `data` represents as 12 bits per pixel.

Comment: Before you do `img = (img / 256).astype('uint8')`, what's the `dtype` of `img`, and what is the range of values it holds?

Comment: @DanMašek. The ```dtype``` is ```uint16``` and max value is ```4095```

Comment: Given the max value being 4095, and you scaling it down by 256, the resulting image will only contain intensities between 0 and 15 inclusive. 15 is still quite dark gray -- if I take some image editor and draw something with that colour on pure black background, I can barely see it.

Comment: @DanMašek. I understand but can videowriter handle the 16bit image? I also added the image of ```img``` just before adding to writer

Comment: I'm not sure about the 16bit support. However, if you know that the input images don't go above 4095 (i guess your source is 12bit), then instead of dividing by 256, divide only by 16.

Comment: @thanks. It generates the video but quality is bad and is there is possibility to improve the image quality ? or make it as a color image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230123/discussion-between-reddy2810-and-dan-masek).

Comment: @Reddy2810 in case it's still relevant... You may try applying simple linear contrast enhancement. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449340/contrast-enhancement-using-a-percentage-cumulative-count-in-matplolib) is an example I posted. In case the video is supposed to be colored, it is most likely that frames are in [Bayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) format (we can't tell from the image in your post, because it is not in the original resolution).

Comment: @DanMašek I added the original image. Maybe you can help me now ?

Comment: @Rotem I added the original image. Maybe you can help me now ? –

Comment: @Reddy2810 The image looks weird (has bright and dark columns). How did you convert it for 12 bits to 8 bits? Why are you posting JPEG and not PNG?

Comment: @Rotem it is initially a 16bit image and now i convert it into 8 bit image. ```img = (img / 16).astype('uint8')```

Comment: Are you sure all the pixels of `img` were in range [0, 4095] before `img = (img / 16).astype('uint8')`? It looks like there are many cases of data overflow...

Comment: Yes. The min and max values for ```img``` are 0 and 4095.

Comment: Can you post the image as 3648 x 992 without dividing it by 16 ? I suppose `img = (img / 16)` looses some important data. You can read the image as type `uint8` or use [view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) to view the `uint16` data as `uint8`. Please post the image in **PNG** format (not JPEG). Please post the camera model if you can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230269/discussion-between-reddy2810-and-rotem).

Comment: Just a thought... 12 bits/pixel could possibly be YUV with subsampled U and V, e.g. NV21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the way you are unpacking the 12 bits is incorrect.

- Lower 4 bits of `mid_uint8` are the upper 4 bits of `fst_uint12` (and `fst_uint8` are the lower 8 bits).
  `mid_uint8   ********   fst_uint8   ********`
  `fst_uint12      ||||               ||||||||`
  Code for unpacking `fst_uint12`:

  ```
   fst_uint12 = fst_uint8 + ((mid_uint8 & 0xF) << 8)
  ```
- Upper 4 bits of `mid_uint8` are the lower 4 bits of `snd_uint12` (and `lst_uint8` are the upper 8 bits).
  `lst_uint8   ********   mid_uint8   ********`
  `snd_uint12  ||||||||               ||||`    
  Code for unpacking `snd_uint12`:

  ```
   snd_uint12 = (lst_uint8 << 4) + (mid_uint8 >> 4)
  ```

After building the 12 bits image, the result looks like [CFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_filter_array) (Color Filter Array) image.
The CFA is not classic Bayer filter, but something else I can't identify.
Note: It could be that my interpretation is wrong, and it's not Color Filter Array at all.

---

Here is a code that reads `'data1.out'`, unpack the 12 bits, and convert to BGR:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

width, height = 1824, 992  # Image width and height.

data = np.fromfile('data1.out', np.uint16)  # Read data from file into 1D NumPy array as type uin16
data = data.astype(np.uint8)  # np.max(data) is 255, so I have to assume data is actually uint8 - convert data to uint8.

# Separate data into low, mid and high bytes - before unpacking 12 bits elements.
fst_uint8 = data[0::3].astype(np.uint16)  # Convert to uint16 (used at the next stage).
mid_uint8 = data[1::3].astype(np.uint16)
lst_uint8 = data[2::3].astype(np.uint16)

# Unpack first 12 bits:
# Lower 4 bits of mid_uint8 are the upper 4 bits of fst_uint12 (and fst_uint8 are the lower 8 bits).
# mid_uint8   ********   fst_uint8   ********
# fst_uint12      ||||               ||||||||
fst_uint12 = fst_uint8 + ((mid_uint8 & 0xF) << 8)

# Unpack second 12 bits:
# Upper 4 bits of mid_uint8 are the lower 4 bits of snd_uint12 (and lst_uint8 are the upper 8 bits).
# lst_uint8   ********   mid_uint8   ********
# snd_uint12  ||||||||               ||||
snd_uint12 = (lst_uint8 << 4) + (mid_uint8 >> 4)

# Interleave fst_uint12 and snd_uint12
data_uint12 = np.zeros(len(fst_uint12)*2)
data_uint12[0::2] = fst_uint12
data_uint12[1::2] = snd_uint12

# Reshape data_uint12 into img
img = np.reshape(data_uint12, (height, width))

# Convert to uint8 - simply divide by 16 (loose some accuracy, but its good enough for getting a sample).
img = (img//16).astype(np.uint8)

# Apply demosaic - not sure it is correct.
bgr_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_GB2BGR)

bgr_img = cv2.resize(bgr_img, (912, 496)) # Resize bgr_img

# Show images for testing
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('bgr_img', bgr_img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:

`bgr_img`:
*Image was removed due to OP request.*

`img`:
*Image was removed due to OP request.*

---

**Applying contrast enhancement:**

Example for linear contrast enhancement (see: [Contrast enhancement using a percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449340/contrast-enhancement-using-a-percentage-cumulative-count-in-matplolib)).

```
# Reshape data_uint12 into img
img = np.reshape(data_uint12, (height, width))

# Crop relevant ROI
img = img[40:978, 100:1714]

# Apply linear "stretch" - lo goes to 0, and hi goes to 1
lo, hi = np.percentile(img, (1, 99))  # 1% - Low percentile, 99% - High percentile
stretch_img = (img.astype(float) - lo) / (hi-lo)
stretch_img = np.maximum(np.minimum(stretch_img*255, 255), 0).astype(np.uint8)  # Multiply by 255, clamp range to [0, 255] and convert to uint8

# Apply demosaic - not sure it is correct.
stretch_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(stretch_img, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_GB2BGR)
stretch_bgr = cv2.resize(stretch_bgr, (912, 496)) # Resize bgr_img
```

Example for [CLAHE](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html) (the example applied gray-scale image):

```
# Create a CLAHE object (Arguments are optional).
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
cl1 = clahe.apply(cv2.cvtColor(stretch_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))  # Convert BGR to gray-scale and apply contrast enhancement.
```

---

Results:

`stretch_bgr`:
*Image was removed due to OP request.*

`cl1`:
*Image was removed due to OP request.*

---

### Update:

Processing **RCCC** Color Filter Array:

As Dan Mašek commented, the raw image format applies [RCCC Color Filter Array](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RCCC_color_filter_array_(R1C1).svg).

[image]

The specific ordering is:
`CR`
`CC`
(The red channel is on the top right corner of every 2x2 pixels).

We can reconstruct the "clear channel" (luminance) according to the following paper: [Engineer-to-Engineer Note](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/EE358.pdf):

```
# Reshape data_uint12 into img
img = np.reshape(data_uint12, (height, width))


# The CFA is RCCC
# Color Filter Array ordering:
# CR
# CC

img = np.reshape(data_uint12, (height, width)).astype(np.uint16)

img = img[40:978, 100:1714]  # Crop relevant ROI

# Reconstruct C (clear pixel value), in position of red pixels.
# Apply convolution as described here:
# https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/EE358.pdf

k = np.array([[ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  0,  2,  0,  0],
              [-1,  2,  4,  2, -1],
              [ 0,  0,  2,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0]], float) * (1.0/8.0)

tmp_img = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, k)  # Convolve image with kernel k
tmp_img = np.minimum(tmp_img, 4095)  # Limit result to valid range of 12 bits.

# Image of "clear" pixels - replace original "red" pixels with values of red pixels after filter2D.
c_img = img.copy()
c_img[0::2, 1::2] = tmp_img[0::2, 1::2]

cv2.imshow('c_img', c_img*16)  # Show image for testing
cv2.waitKey()

cv2.imwrite('c_img.png', cv2.resize((c_img//16).astype(np.uint8), (912, 496)))
```

**Fixing the colors:**
Since there are only clear pixels and red pixels, we can not reconstruct the green and the blue colors.
The code below builds a "false colors" reddish image.
The "reddish image" is not an exact reconstruction of the red color, it's just resembles how the image is supposed to look (given there are only red and clear channels).

For building the image, I used the following stages:

- Extract red color channel by resizing - assume it's good enough.
- Compute green and blue channels from clear and red channels (assuming green and blue are equal).
- Convert from BGR to YCrCb color format.
- Place values of 128 in Cb channel (eliminate the blue color).
- Apply CLAHE contrast enhancement on Y channel.
- Convert from YCrCb back to BGR.

Here is the code:

```
# Extract red color channel by resizing - assume it's good enough.
r_img = cv2.resize(img[0::2, 1::2], (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))


# In YUV color space: Y = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B
# We know Y (Y applies clear channel) and R, but we don't know G and B.
# For simplicity, assume G = B.
# Y = 0.2126*R + (0.7152+0.0722)*G ==> G = (Y - 0.2126*R)/(0.7152+0.0722) and B = G
g_img = c_img - 0.2126*r_img / (0.7152+0.0722)
b_img = g_img
tmp_bgr_img = (np.dstack((b_img, g_img, r_img))//16).astype(np.uint8)  # Merge channels and convert to uint8

# Convert BGR to YCrCb
ycrcb_img = cv2.cvtColor(tmp_bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)

# Cr approximates red color hue
# Cb approximates blue color hue
# Place 128 in Cb, because there is no blue color (keep only Cr)
ycrcb_img[:, :, 2] = 128

# Apply CLAHE enhancement on Y channel - remark: the conventional way is converting BGR to LAB and apply CLAHE on L.
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
ycrcb_img[:, :, 0] = clahe.apply(ycrcb_img[:, :, 0])
    
# Convert back to BGR - build image with gray and red colors:
reddish_bgr_img = cv2.cvtColor(ycrcb_img, cv2.COLOR_YCrCb2BGR)

cv2.imshow('reddish_bgr_img', reddish_bgr_img)  # Show image for testing
cv2.waitKey()

cv2.imwrite('reddish_bgr_img.png', cv2.resize(reddish_bgr_img, (912, 496)))
```

Result:
*Image was removed due to OP request.*

Comment: thanks @Rotem this is lot better but can improve the color quality to see the traffic signs or vehicles in the scenario as brighter ?

Comment: I don't think you should have accepted my answer. Wait until the bounty expires - there is a chance you get a better answer.

Comment: Does the color makes sense? Is it a bi-chromatic sensor?

Comment: Yes is it possible get color image without decreasing the image quality.

Comment: Contrast enhancement is not an issue. I just can't get the colors right. Do you know the model of the Camera (or Sensor)? Do you know the CFA (Color Filter Array) arrangement? There are too many options. For examples see: [Color Filter Array Designs](http://www.quadibloc.com/other/cfaint.htm).

Comment: Look in the chat (as OP suggested couple of times). I'm pretty confident this is a RCCC array.

Comment: I think I also show an easier way to unpack the data there... just work with 32bit integers. Then you just have to shift the inputs appropriately, and then shift/mast got the 12 bit pieces out. | Since you already wrote this up, feel free to use what i described in the chat to improve your answer (and maybe make an attribution if you feel like it) ;) .

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you for clearing that up. I'm pretty confident this is a RCCC too.

Comment: @Reddy2810 I corrected my answer after knowing the CFA configuration is RCCC, as commented by Dan Mašek.

Comment: No problem. Nice update, just one comment -- both of your new code examples have a `
cv2.imshow` not followed by `cv2.waitKey` ;)

Comment: @Reddy2810 I have issued a removal request from [imgur](https://imgur.com/removalrequest). I am not sure if the images are going to be deleted.