# Python, Forcing pixel values in range [0,1]

Tags: python, image, range, pixel

I have some grayscale images (*img* in the code) whose pixels has value from 0 to 4095.
My Jupiter Notebook shows me these images with a violet-yellow scale which is not related to the real graduation.

I try to use the MinMaxScaler but it seems to be any effects

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
for img in test:
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1), copy = False)
    img = scaler.fit_transform(img)
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: The "violet-yellow scale" is probably the result of a **colormap**. Try selecting a gray colormap.

Comment: True, thanks, I succeeded in change into another colormap. Now I have alredy the range problem to fix

Comment: I never used `sklearn.preprocessing`... You may try "linear stretching" as in my following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450515/4926757).